# How do I set up document versions in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: document-library, versioning, information-management

I want to setup document versions like this:

Everytime I edit a document the version has to change and if this possible I want to turn it back to a previous version if this is needed.

Can you provide me the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to library settings from the ribbon. You should see an option for "Version Settings". Select "Create minor and major versions". You might also want to turn on "Require Checkout".